# window.location.assign(varString) wont work

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink, forward, assign

I have java script function to check the URL and split it,
I ask a question and depends on the answer it will forward the user page
all works fine until I use window.location.assign();
with string inside (=window.location.assign(path);) instead of fixed URL (=window.location.assign("http://stackoverflow.com");)
what can i do?
thanks...

```
var register=...;
var login=...;
function link(type) {
var urlPath = document.URL.split("/");
if (type == "register") {
    var path= urlPath[2] + register;
    window.location.assign(path);
}
else {
    var path = urlPath[2] + login;
    window.location.assign(path);

}
event.preventDefault();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the full URL.

```
window.location.assign(urlPath[0]+'/'+urlPath[1]+'/'+urlPath[2]+register);

window.location.assign(urlPath[0]+'/'+urlPath[1]+'/'+urlPath[2]+path);
```

Or

```
window.location.assign(window.location.origin+register);

window.location.assign(window.location.origin+path);
```

Comment: do you know what is the reason for that?

Comment: @user1913615, I suppose it could have been done differently, but whatever you pass to `assign` becomes the URL in the address bar. It needs to be the whole thing.